# MYSQL Err #1072 doesn't exist in table when specifying FK

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql, so sorry if this is a trivial problem. Problem is when I create the second table I get the error:

> key `iplogger_redirect_key` doesn't exist.

Here's my code:

```
DROP DATABASE iploggerdb;

CREATE DATABASE iploggerdb;

USE iploggerdb;

CREATE TABLE iplogger_info_table(
    iplogger_redirect_key CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    access_key CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    creation_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    creator_ip VARCHAR(45),
    original_url VARCHAR(2000)
);

CREATE TABLE logs_table(
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    iplogger_redirect_key FOREIGN KEY (iplogger_redirect_key) REFERENCES iplogger_info_table(iplogger_redirect_key),
    logged_ip VARCHAR(45),
    logged_dns_server VARCHAR(45),
    logged_ip_country_city VARCHAR(200),
    logged_hostname VARCHAR(200),
    logged_user_agent VARCHAR(150),
    logged_referrer VARCHAR(2000),
    logged_ip_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Add a definition for iplogger_redirect_key and put the foreign key constraint on a separate line

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct `FOREIGN KEY` part:

```
CREATE TABLE logs_table(
   id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   iplogger_redirect_key CHAR(8),
   CONSTRAINT fk_name FOREIGN KEY (iplogger_redirect_key)  
    REFERENCES iplogger_info_table(iplogger_redirect_key),
   ...
)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e2b3d02ce8f4589b8824972574a0c4a)**